# How to create functions in Mysql

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I try to implement this function that I found in another post

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnNumberToWords(@Number as BIGINT)

RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)

AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @Below20 TABLE (ID int identity(0,1), Word varchar(32))

  DECLARE @Below100 TABLE (ID int identity(2,1), Word varchar(32))

  INSERT @Below20 (Word) VALUES

                    ( 'Zero'), ('One'),( 'Two' ), ( 'Three'),

                    ( 'Four' ), ( 'Five' ), ( 'Six' ), ( 'Seven' ),

                    ( 'Eight'), ( 'Nine'), ( 'Ten'), ( 'Eleven' ),

                    ( 'Twelve' ), ( 'Thirteen' ), ( 'Fourteen'),

                    ( 'Fifteen' ), ('Sixteen' ), ( 'Seventeen'),

                    ('Eighteen' ), ( 'Nineteen' )

   INSERT @Below100 VALUES ('Twenty'), ('Thirty'),('Forty'), ('Fifty'),

                           ('Sixty'), ('Seventy'), ('Eighty'), ('Ninety')

DECLARE @English varchar(1024) =

(

    SELECT Case

    WHEN @Number = 0 THEN  ''

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1 AND 19

    THEN (SELECT Word FROM @Below20 WHERE ID=@Number)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 20 AND 99  

    THEN  (SELECT Word FROM @Below100 WHERE ID=@Number/10)+ '-' +

       dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 10)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 100 AND 999  

    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 100))+' Hundred '+

     dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 100)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000 AND 999999  

    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000))+' Thousand '+

     dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000) 

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000 AND 999999999  

    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000))+' Million '+

     dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 999999999999  

    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000))+' Billion '+

     dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000000 AND 999999999999999  

    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000000))+' Trillion '+

     dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000000)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000000000 AND 999999999999999999  

    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000000000))+' Quadrillion '+

     dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000000000)

    WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000000000000 AND 999999999999999999999  

    THEN  (dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number / 1000000000000000000))+' Quintillion '+

     dbo.fnNumberToWords( @Number % 1000000000000000000)

    ELSE ' INVALID INPUT' END

 )



 SELECT @English = RTRIM(@English)

 SELECT @English = RTRIM(LEFT(@English,len(@English)-1))

             WHERE RIGHT(@English,1)='-'

 RETURN (@English)

 END

 GO
```

But at the very beginning `fnNumberToWords(@Number as BIGINT)` I got an error `@Number is not valid at this position, expecting identifier`.

And if I try something like this `fnNumberToWords(numberConv BIGINT)` and remove the `AS` before `Begin`
I got an error in the first `Declare`: `Declare is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting:`

I'm new with store procedures and functions in Mysql, and I don't know how to create them or why I have those errors

Comment: You might want to follow documentation around syntaxes in MySQL. The code to u shared follows SQL server syntax.

Comment: There is no such thing as table variables in mysql only temporary tables. and the rest of the function makes me think the code is sqlserver so is this question wrongly tagged or are you trying to convert to mysql?

Comment: @P.Salmon actually convert it hahaha I didn't know it was for sqlserver